Why is StackOverflow in Maintenenace mode but not in Maintenance Mode?
Nothing about on going Maintenance post here.
But on my main Browser (Firefox 103.0.3 on Windows 10) I get.

But in A private browser Window it is not Maintenance Mode or in a different Browser it is not in Maintenance Mode.
I've restarted browser, cleared cookie, disabled all extensions, etc but nothing helps.
Update:
According List of planned Maintenance there was not any Maintenance listed for today.
While the Solution is the same as Stack Overflow in read-only mode for past 2 days that seemed to a leftover from planned maintenance.
Though in the comments on linked answer there are suggestions that a Cloudfare DNS issue can randomly happen and this is probably an instance of that happening.

https://filecamp.com/support/problem-solving/hard-refresh/#:~:text=Firefox:%20Quick%20hard%20refresh%20can%20be%20done,Ctrl%20key%20and%20press%20the%20F5%20key.

Should have said I tried that as the first thing, but as a harder refresh I said I restarted the browser

It seems like a bug that Cloudflare cookies keep sticking people to servers that can’t serve then.

It seems there was something in Firefox's "Site Data" that was causing this.
I cleared that and it works fine now.

Same answer already given.
